# Docker container exiting very slow and with code 137

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my project, I'm using Docker, and everything works fine except when I try to stop it. When I press the stop button in Docker Desktop, all containers stop normally except for one: `my-project-frontend`. The `my-project-frontend` container takes significantly longer to stop (around 10x-11x) compared to other containers, and its status becomes `Exited (137)` instead of the expected `Exited`.

I came across [this](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25492#discussioncomment-3248091) GitHub answer which states that

> the container was killed by ‘OOM killer’ (Out of Memory). This happens when there isn’t enough memory in the container for running the process.

However, I have verified that this is not the case because none of the images are utilizing even 1/10th of the available memory (I checked using the [Resource Usage](https://open.docker.com/extensions/marketplace?extensionId=docker/resource-usage-extension) extension).

Here are the relevant files for my project:

```yaml
# ./docker-compose.yml
services:
  database:
    build:
      context: ./Database
    image: my-dockerhub-username/my-project-database:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    container_name: my-project-database
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./Backend
    image: my-dockerhub-username/my-project-backend:latest
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - database
    container_name: my-project-backend
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./Frontend
    image: my-dockerhub-username/my-project-frontend:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: my-project-frontend
  reverse-proxy:
    build:
      context: ./ReverseProxy
    image: my-dockerhub-username/my-project-reverse-proxy:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
    container_name: my-project-reverse-proxy
name: my-project
```

```
# ./Frontend/Dockerfile
# my frontend is running on Nuxt 3 if it makes any difference
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

FROM base AS deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci

FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/.output ./.output
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "./.output/server/index.mjs"]
```

Screenshot from Docker Desktop:
[image: screenshot]

Edit: logs from frontend container:

```
2023-06-11 09:08:01 Listening http://[::]:3000
```

(not very helpful)

Comment: have you checked the frontend container logs?

Answer (score 0):

Even if your container is not utilizing a significant amount of memory based on the resource usage you checked, the `OOM` killer may be triggered in certain situations where memory is constrained. The `OOM` killer prioritizes terminating processes to free up memory when it detects memory exhaustion.
You can try and specify the memory limits for the container in your Docker Compose file by adding a `mem_limit` or `mem_reservation` property under the frontend service.

```
frontend:
  build:
    context: <your-context>
  image: <your-docker-image-name>
  ports:
    - <"PORTS:PORTS">
  container_name: <your-container-name>
  mem_limit: 512m
```

You can increase the memory limit based on your project usage

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help. Even with greater limit.